# camel assertMockEndpointsSatisfied timeout is not working

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm using Apache camel using spring boot version `3.16.0` with Junit 5 to test my routes.

I'm trying to set the timeout for mock assertion in my Unit test using `assertMockEndpointsSatisfied(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` **but when running my test it takes more that 2 seconds (about 30s) in order to fail the test.**

```
    private static final String DIRECT_START_ENDPOINT = "direct:start";
    private static final String MOCK_ENDPOINT = "mock:end";

    @EndpointInject(value = DIRECT_START_ENDPOINT)
    private Endpoint fromEndpoint;

    @EndpointInject(value = MOCK_ENDPOINT)
    private MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

    // code here

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        MyRoute myRoute = new MyRoute(());
        myRoute.setInput(fromEndpoint.getEndpointUri());
        myRoute.setOutput(mockEndpoint.getEndpointUri());
        return inputRoute;
}

    @Test
    void myTest() throws InterruptedException {
        var messages = List.of("msg1", "msg2", "msg3");
        // given
        mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(3);
        mockEndpoint.allMessages().body().isInstanceOf(MyObject.class);
        // when
        messages.forEach(message -> template.sendBody(fromEndpoint.getEndpointUri(), message));
        // then should fail 
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Can you show how your `mockEndpoint` is created & initialized ?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco yes, I have updated the code example

Comment: I m facing exactly the same issue! where are you able to fix it?